# inertia count sparse matrix with dense low-rank perturbation

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigenvalues, dense-matrix, matrix-factorization, update

I would like to determine the number of negative eigenvalues (inertia count) of the $(N \times N)$ symmetric real matrix $K - \sigma M$, with $K$ a positive-definite sparse matrix and $M$ a positive-semidefinite matrix such that $M = Z Z^T$ with $Z$ a dense $(N \times r)$ full column-rank matrix, $r \ll N$, $\sigma > 0$.

The matrix $K - \sigma M$ is a low-rank perturbation of $K$ and cannot be assembled into memory because $N$ is very large. If $M$ was sparse, the LDL factorization $K - \sigma M = L D L^T$ would be possible and would give the inertia count through the inertia count of $D$.

Comment: Even if $N$ is huge, can you factorize $K$?

Comment: Yes, I can. It is not possible to factorize $K - \sigma M$ because it $M$ is dense and cannot be assembled. I edited and replaced 'huge' with 'very large'.

Comment: If you can factor K and store/apply Z, you should be able to use the Woodbury identity to build the solution operator (inverse) for K-sigma*M. This isn't quite the finish line, but could be a start because it lets you probe for near-zero eigenvalues using inverse iteration.

Comment: Yes, thanks to Woodbury matrix identity I am able to efficiently solve for $\textbf{x}$ the linear system ${( K - \sigma M )}^{-1} \textbf{f}$ for a given real vector $\textbf{f}$. What I would like to do is to solve the generalized eigenvalue problem $K \boldsymbol{\varphi} = \lambda M \boldsymbol{\varphi}$ for many eigenpairs by spectrum slicing. To do so, I need to divide the sprectum in subintervals for which I know the number of eigenvalues present. An accurate inertia count at several $\sigma$'s would be perfect; a rough approximation of the spectral density would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on rchilton1980 answer and the comments that have followed.

Let $K = L L^T$ be the Cholesky factorization of $K$.

Let $Y = L^{-1} Z$ , computed by forward substitution.

Let $\mathcal{I} (A)$ denote the number of negative eigenvalues of a given matrix $A$ (negative index of inertia).

We seek to compute $\mathcal{I}_\sigma = \mathcal{I} (K - \sigma M) = \mathcal{I} (L L^T - \sigma Z Z^T)$ .

Since the inertia is invariant under a change of basis (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), inertia count $\mathcal{I}_\sigma$ can be written as

$\mathcal{I}_\sigma = \mathcal{I} \left( L^{-1} \left( L L^T - \sigma Z Z^T \right) L^{-T} \right) = \mathcal{I} \left( I_N - \sigma Y Y^T \right) = \mathcal{I} \left( \frac{1}{\sigma} I_N - Y Y^T \right)$ .

Now, it should be noted that $Y Y^T$ and $Y^T Y$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues (see for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition). The eigendecomposition

$\left( Y Y^T \right) \Phi_Y = \Phi_Y \begin{bmatrix} \Lambda_Y & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ such that $Y Y^T = \Phi_Y \begin{bmatrix} \Lambda_Y & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \Phi_Y^T$ and $\Phi_Y \Phi_Y^T = I_N$  yields

$\mathcal{I}_\sigma = \mathcal{I} \left( \Phi_Y \left( \frac{1}{\sigma} I_N - \begin{bmatrix} \Lambda_Y & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \right) \Phi_Y^T \right)$ and consequently,

$\mathcal{I}_\sigma = \mathcal{I} \left( \frac{1}{\sigma} I_N - \begin{bmatrix} \Lambda_Y & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \right)$ , which is given by $\mathcal{I}_\sigma = \mathcal{I} \left( \frac{1}{\sigma} I_r - \Lambda_Y \right)$ .

Matrix $\Lambda_Y$ is the diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues of $Y^T Y$. Once $\Lambda_Y$ is calculated (independent of $\sigma$), then $\mathcal{I}_\sigma$ can be computed at no cost for any $\sigma > 0$.

---

Alternatively, we now show how it is possible to compute all the $r$ finite eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors of the generalized eigenvalue problem (GEP) $K \Phi = M \Phi \Lambda$ , with the same cost.

Recalling that $M = Z Z^T$, it can be deduced that the eigenvectors belong to the image (column space) of $(N \times r)$ real matrix $S = K^{-1} Z$ (see for instance [Large-scale generalized eigenvalue problem with low rank LHS matrix](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2294/large-scale-generalized-eigenvalue-problem-with-low-rank-lhs-matrix?rq=1)).

Applying Rayleigh-Ritz (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Ritz_method) to above GEP (Galerkin projection onto $S$), a $(r \times r)$ GEP is obtained,

$(S^T K S) X = (S^T M S) X \Lambda$.

That is to say, an eigenvector $\boldsymbol{\varphi}$ of the $(N \times N)$ GEP is written as $\boldsymbol{\varphi} = S \textbf{x}$ with $\textbf{x}$ an eigenvector of the $(r \times r)$ GEP (that is, $\Phi = S X$). This procedure yields exact eigenpairs since $S$ spans the sought eigenspace.

Now, it can be observed that $S^T K S = Y^T Y$ and $S^T M S = {(Y^T Y)}^2$. Introducing the notation $A = Y^T Y$, the $(r \times r)$ GEP writes $A X = A^2 X \Lambda$, which is equivalent to the standard eigenvalue problem (SEP) $A X = X \Lambda^{-1}$ . It can be recognized that $\Lambda = \Lambda_Y^{-1}$.

---

As a conclusion, the proposed approach for inertia count is as costly as directly computing all the eigenvalues of the associated GEP. The cost (dense eigenvalue problem with dimension $r$) rapidly increases with $r$.

It should be noted that the cost for computing $\mathcal{I}_\sigma$ for one given $\sigma > 0$ can be less than that of computing all the eigenvalues, as one also has $\mathcal{I}_\sigma = \mathcal{I} \left( \frac{1}{\sigma} I_r - Y^T Y \right)$, which can be obtained by LDL factorization of $\frac{1}{\sigma} I_r - Y^T Y$.

My next question would be how to determine the inertia count of $K_\sigma - \sigma Z Z^T$ with $K_\sigma = K - \sigma M_0$ , in which $M_0$ is a sparse $(N \times N)$ symmetric positive-semidefinite matrix. The difference with the above is that $K_\sigma$ is not positive definite. I am presently using the above developments to answer this question.

Edit: See below for the answer to this question.

---

We seek to compute $\mathcal{I}_\sigma = \mathcal{I} \left( K - \sigma M \right)$ with $M = M_0 + Z Z^T$.

We have $\mathcal{I}_\sigma = \mathcal{I} \left( K_\sigma - \sigma Z Z^T \right)$ with $K_\sigma = K - \sigma M_0$ a full-rank sparse symmetric matrix.

The LDL factorization of $K_\sigma$ is performed, which yields $K_\sigma = L_\sigma D_\sigma L_\sigma^T$.

Thus, we obtain $\mathcal{I}_\sigma = \mathcal{I} \left( L_\sigma^{-1} \left( K_\sigma - \sigma Z Z^T \right) L_\sigma^{-T} \right) = \mathcal{I} \left( D_\sigma - \sigma Y_\sigma Y_\sigma^T \right)$ with $Y_\sigma = L_\sigma^{-1} Z$. Which gives $\mathcal{I}_\sigma = \left( \frac{D_\sigma}{\sigma} - Y_\sigma Y_\sigma^T \right)$.

Introducing the $(N \times N)$ GEP $\left( \frac{D_\sigma}{\sigma} \right) \Phi = \left( Y_\sigma Y_\sigma^T \right) \Phi \Lambda$ such that $\Phi^T \left( \frac{D_\sigma}{\sigma} \right) \Phi = \Lambda$ and $\Phi^T \left( Y_\sigma Y_\sigma^T \right) \Phi = I_N $ (unit mass eigenvector normalization), we obtain $\mathcal{I}_\sigma = \mathcal{I} \left( \Phi^T \left( \frac{D_\sigma}{\sigma} - Y_\sigma Y_\sigma^T  \right) \Phi \right) = \mathcal{I} \left( \Lambda - I_N \right)$. This GEP cannot be solved.

Similarly to before, the $r$ eigenvectors associated with the $r$ finite eigenvalues belong to the column space of $S_\sigma = {\left( \frac{D\sigma}{\sigma} \right)}^{-1} Y_\sigma$. The $(r \times r)$ GEP $\left( S_\sigma^T \left( \frac{D_\sigma}{\sigma} \right) S_\sigma \right) X = \left( S_\sigma^T \left( Y_\sigma Y_\sigma^T \right) S_\sigma \right) X \Lambda_f$ allows to obtain the finite eigenvalues $\Lambda_f$ of the $(N \times N)$ GEP. Let $A_\sigma = S_\sigma^T \left( \frac{D_\sigma}{\sigma} \right) S_\sigma$. One has $A_\sigma = Y_\sigma^T {\left( \frac{D_\sigma}{\sigma} \right)}^{-1} Y_\sigma$ and $S_\sigma^T \left( Y_\sigma Y_\sigma^T \right) S_\sigma = A_\sigma^2$. Thus, the $r$ finite eigenvalues $\Lambda_f$ can be deduced from the $(r \times r)$ SEP $A_\sigma X = X \Lambda_f^{-1}$.

Let $\Lambda_i$ denote the matrix of the $N - r$ infinite eigenvalues.
We have $\mathcal{I}_\sigma = \mathcal{I} \left( \Lambda - I_N \right) = \mathcal{I} \left( \Lambda_f - I_r \right) + \mathcal{I} \left( \Lambda_i - I_{N - r} \right)$. Let $\mathcal{I}_f = \mathcal{I} \left( \Lambda_f - I_r \right)$ and $\mathcal{I}_i = \mathcal{I} \left( \Lambda_i - I_{N - r} \right)$. We have $\mathcal{I}_f = \mathcal{I} \left( X^T A_\sigma^{-1} X - X^T X \right)$ because $X^{-1} = X^T$, and consequently, $\mathcal{I}_f = \mathcal{I} \left( A_\sigma^{-1} - I_r \right)$. Since for a real scalar $a$ we have $a^{-1} \in ] - \infty , 1 [ \,\,\, \Rightarrow \,\, a \in ] - \infty , 0 [ \, \cup  \,] 1 , + \infty [\,$, it can be seen that $\mathcal{I}_f = \mathcal{I} \left( A_\sigma^{-1} - I_r \right) = \mathcal{I} \left( A_\sigma \right) + \mathcal{I} \left( I_r - A_\sigma \right)$.

On the other hand, we have $\mathcal{I}_i = \mathcal{I} \left( \Lambda_i - I_{N - r} \right) = \mathcal{I} \left( \Lambda_i \right)$ ($\mathcal{I}_i$ is given by the number of negative infinite eigenvalues). Since $\mathcal{I} \left( \Lambda \right) = \mathcal{I} \left( \Lambda_f \right) + \mathcal{I} \left( \Lambda_i \right)$ and $\mathcal{I} \left( \Lambda \right) = \mathcal{I} \left( \Phi^T \left( \frac{D_\sigma}{\sigma} \right) \Phi \right) = \mathcal{I} \left( \frac{D_\sigma}{\sigma} \right) = \mathcal{I} \left( D_\sigma \right)$, we obtain $\mathcal{I}_i = \mathcal{I} \left( D_\sigma \right) - \mathcal{I} \left( \Lambda_f \right)$. In addition, we have $\mathcal{I} \left( \Lambda_f \right) = \mathcal{I} \left( \Lambda_f^{-1} \right) = \mathcal{I} \left( A_\sigma \right)$. Therefore, we obtain $\mathcal{I}_i = \mathcal{I} \left( D_\sigma \right) - \mathcal{I} \left( A_\sigma \right)$.

As a conclusion, it can be deduced that $\mathcal{I}_\sigma = \mathcal{I} \left( D_\sigma \right) + \mathcal{I} \left( I_r - A_\sigma \right)$.

Summary of the operations:

- LDL factorization of $(N \times N)$ sparse matrix $K_\sigma = L_\sigma D_\sigma L_\sigma^T$
- Solve $Y_\sigma = L_\sigma^{-1} Z$ by forward substitutions
- Assemble $A_\sigma = Y_\sigma^T {\left( \frac{D_\sigma}{\sigma} \right)}^{-1} Y_\sigma$
- LDL factorization of $(r \times r)$ dense matrix $ I_r - A_\sigma$

Answer (score 5):

Upon further examination, I do think the Woodbury identity can be used to solve this problem. With it we can write:

$\left( \mathbf K - \sigma \mathbf Z \mathbf Z^T \right)^{-1} = \mathbf K^{-1} - \mathbf K^{-1} \mathbf Z \left(-\frac{1}{\sigma}\mathbf I + \mathbf Z^{T} \mathbf K^{-1} \mathbf Z\right)^{-1}\mathbf Z^T \mathbf K^{-1}$

Since $\mathbf K$ is symmetric positive definite, you can write $\mathbf K^{-1}$ in terms of the Cholesky triangle $\mathbf L$:

$\mathbf K^{-1} = \left(\mathbf L \mathbf L^T \right)^{-1} = \mathbf L^{-T} \mathbf L^{-1}$

Insert this representation, then simplify by introducing $\mathbf Y = \mathbf L^{-1} \mathbf Z$:

$\left( \mathbf K - \sigma \mathbf Z \mathbf Z^T \right)^{-1} = \mathbf L^{-T} \mathbf L^{-1} - \mathbf L^{-T} \mathbf Y \left(-\frac{1}{\sigma}\mathbf I + \mathbf Y^{T} \mathbf Y\right)^{-1}\mathbf Y^T \mathbf L^{-1}$

Now regroup:

$\left( \mathbf K - \sigma \mathbf Z \mathbf Z^T \right)^{-1} = \mathbf L^{-T} \left[ \mathbf I - \mathbf Y \left(-\frac{1}{\sigma}\mathbf I + \mathbf Y^{T} \mathbf Y\right)^{-1}\mathbf Y^T \right] \mathbf L^{-1}$

This is progress. It's not quite an $\mathbf L \mathbf D \mathbf L^T$ decomposition, but it might be good enough in the sense that it's a symmetric real congruence transform of the perturbed $\mathbf K$. So the square-bracketed part, despite being non-diagonal, still embeds the inertia. To proceed, introduce the matrix $\mathbf S = \left(-\frac{1}{\sigma}\mathbf I + \mathbf Y^{T} \mathbf Y\right)$, which we should be able to tabulate explicitly because it's so small (only $r \times r$). We can also readily compute/apply its inverse (using dense $\mathbf L \mathbf D \mathbf L^T$):

$\left( \mathbf K - \sigma \mathbf Z \mathbf Z^T \right)^{-1} = \mathbf L^{-T} \left[ \mathbf I - \mathbf Y \mathbf S^{-1}\mathbf Y^T \right] \mathbf L^{-1}$

Continue teasing at the bracketed part to get it to display its eigenvalues. Compute the $\mathbf Q \mathbf R$ decomposition of the tall/skinny matrix $\mathbf Y$:

$\left( \mathbf K - \sigma \mathbf Z \mathbf Z^T \right)^{-1} = \mathbf L^{-T} \left[ \mathbf I - \left(\mathbf Q \mathbf R\right)\mathbf S^{-1} \left( \mathbf Q \mathbf R \right)^T \right] \mathbf L^{-1}$

Regroup, then compute the eigendecomposition of the (symmetric) matrix $\mathbf R \mathbf S^{-1} \mathbf R^T = \mathbf V \mathbf \Lambda \mathbf V^T$:

$\left( \mathbf K - \sigma \mathbf Z \mathbf Z^T \right)^{-1} = \mathbf L^{-T} \left( \mathbf I - \left(\mathbf Q \mathbf V\right) \mathbf \Lambda \left( \mathbf Q \mathbf V \right)^T \right) \mathbf L^{-1}$

The inner data structure, $\left(\mathbf Q \mathbf V\right) \mathbf \Lambda \left( \mathbf Q \mathbf V \right)^T$, is like a "thin" eigendecomposition. For sake of illustration, fatten it back up by including the implicit zero eigenpairs. Group the handful of non-null eigenvectors into the orthogonal matrix $\mathbf U = \mathbf Q \mathbf V$ and denote the null eigenvectors as $\mathbf N = \text{null}(\mathbf U^T)$:

$\left( \mathbf K - \sigma \mathbf Z \mathbf Z^T \right)^{-1} = \mathbf L^{-T} \left( \mathbf I - \left[\begin{array}{cc} \mathbf U & \mathbf N \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{cc} \mathbf \Lambda & \mathbf 0 \\ \mathbf 0 & \mathbf 0 \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{cc} \mathbf U & \mathbf N \end{array}\right]^T \right) \mathbf L^{-1}$

Of course $\mathbf I$ can be simultaneously diagonalized with any other matrix, so fold it right into this structure:

$\left( \mathbf K - \sigma \mathbf Z \mathbf Z^T \right)^{-1} = \mathbf L^{-T} \left( \left[\begin{array}{cc} \mathbf U & \mathbf N \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{cc} \mathbf I - \mathbf \Lambda & \mathbf 0 \\ \mathbf 0 & \mathbf I \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{cc} \mathbf U & \mathbf N \end{array}\right]^T \right) \mathbf L^{-1}$

This displays eigenvalues/inertia. Since the perturbation was only low rank, most of them will stay positive as indicated the lower right $\mathbf I$ block. However, from any $\mathbf \Lambda_i$ that is greater than one, $\left( \mathbf K - \sigma \mathbf Z \mathbf Z^T \right)^{-1}$ will pick up a negative eigenvalue from the upper left $\mathbf I - \mathbf \Lambda$ block. Since the eigenvalues of $\mathbf K - \sigma \mathbf Z \mathbf Z^T$ are just the reciprocals, the signs/inertia are the same.

To summarize, here are the essential calculations:

- Factor $\mathbf K = \mathbf L \mathbf L^T$, using a sparse direct package.
- Form $\mathbf Y = \mathbf L^{-1} \mathbf Z$, basically a "fat" backsolve across multiple RHS's. But note that this is only "half" of the normal sparse forward/backward solution. A high quality sparse solver package will expose this as an independent calculation (MKL PARDISO does, and so does my own package, MyraMath).
- Initialize the small matrix $\mathbf S = \mathbf Y^T \mathbf Y$. This is basically a "fat" dot product, can be done with BLAS [dsyrk].
- Downdate $\mathbf S = \mathbf S -\frac{1}{\sigma} \mathbf I$.
- Form the $\mathbf L \mathbf D \mathbf L^T$ decomposition of $\mathbf S$. Can be done with LAPACK [dsytrf].
- Form the $\mathbf Q \mathbf R$ decomposition of $\mathbf Y$. Can be done with LAPACK [dgeqrf].
- Form the small matrix $\mathbf T = \mathbf R \mathbf S^{-1} \mathbf R^{T}$. You can use [dystrs] to apply $\mathbf S^{-1}$ to $\mathbf R$ into a temporary, then use [dgemm] to form $\mathbf R \cdot \left( \mathbf S^{-1} \mathbf R \right)$
- Compute the eigendecomposition of $\mathbf T = \mathbf V \mathbf \Lambda \mathbf V^T$, using LAPACK's [dsyevd].
- The number of negative eigenvalues of $\mathbf K - \sigma \mathbf Z \mathbf Z^T$ is the number of $\mathbf \Lambda_i$'s above 1. All the others eigenvalues are positive.

... I think? It seems reasonably efficient to me, as long as you are able to explicitly store $\mathbf Z$ (and therefore $\mathbf Y$). As an aside, note that $\mathbf N$ is never needed/computed, it's only introduced for explanatory purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer. And yes, it is reasonably efficient of a procedure.
So, although $L^{-T} [U N]$ is not lower triangular, the small-dimension matrix in the middle contains the inertia? I am going to implement and see for myself.
In addition, I have the feeling that the small eigendecomposition might be unnecessary, because an LDL factorization would be enough instead? Let me go through the algebra.

Comment: Yes, my claim about equal inertia is all drawing from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence

Comment: Highly encourage you to try it out, hope it works. For small problem sizes you can probably implement this in a few lines of Matlab, and perhaps even ignore the sparsity of $\mathbf K$. Not efficient, but it could be a fast way to find a random counterexample, in the event there is an error in the procedure.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was planning on doing. I will let you know.

Comment: Oh, so I see that the small eigendecomposition is necessary just for the purpose of being able to pass the Identity $I$ into the middle matrix.

Comment: So, I quickly implemented your procedure, and it works! I tried with some random matrices and it always gives the correct inertia.

Comment: Ok, so I understand that what is necessary is the QR decomposition in order to have orthornormal U so that we can pass the Identity $I$ to the middle matrix. So, instead of the eigendecomposition of $T$, I think it is actually also possible to obtain the inertia based on the LDL decomposition of either $I−T$ or $T$. Which should be cheaper, right? I verified that it does work too. It appears obvious while implementing because the output of interest is the number of eigenvalues greater than one; one doesn't need the eigendecomposition to get this.

Comment: Ok, so the inertia $\mathcal{I} ( K − \sigma M)$ of $K− \sigma M$ is given by $r − \mathcal{I}(T)$. But then, $\mathcal{I} (T) = \mathcal{I} (S^{-1}) = \mathcal{I} (S)$. Thus, the QR factorization is not necessary either. So, regarding the cost, to sum up, we only have to pre-compute $Y$ by forward substitution and do the fat product $Y^T Y$ and then, for each shift $\sigma$, we just have to do the LDL factorization of $Y^T Y − \frac{1}{\sigma} I$. So basically, the "online" cost is only of a LDL factorization of a dense $(r \times r)$ matrix. It seems that one cannot do better.

Comment: Nice work! Yes, I think an LDL factorization of $\frac{1}{\sigma}\mathbf I -\mathbf Y^T \mathbf Y$ will work fine. That's much more streamlined. Alternatively, I think you can even pare it down to precomputing the eigendecomposition of $\mathbf Y^T \mathbf Y$ once, then you can find the new eigenvalues for any choice of $\sigma$ by just shifting the resulting $\mathbf \Lambda$ by $\frac{1}{\sigma}\mathbf I$. Maybe? I'm going to let the answer stand because I think it's good exercise to motivate these final conclusions, but will try to add an edit/appendix that mentions your improvements.

Comment: Oh yes, this is a very interesting improvement, as the cost of the inertia count step for spectrum slicing would not grow with the number of slices.
This is indeed correct because: from the eigendecomposition $Y^T Y = \Phi \Lambda \Phi^T$ with $\Phi \Phi^T = I$ it can be seen that $Y^T Y - \frac{1}{\sigma} I = \Phi ( \Lambda - \frac{1}{\sigma} I ) \Phi^T$, for which the inertia is that of $ \Lambda - \frac{1}{\sigma} I$.

Comment: Also, a slight improvement might be to use the SVD of $Y$ in order to avoid the product $Y^T Y$ (it is needed to just compute the singular values: let $\Sigma = \sqrt{\Lambda}$ be the matrix of the singular values, then the inertia is that of $\Sigma - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma}} I$. I verified that it gave the correct result.

Comment: [part 1/3] I was a little confused of how I obtained $\mathcal{I}(K-\sigma M)=r-\mathcal{I}(T)$, although it is correct. Here is a direct way to obtain the result.
Let $\mathcal{C}(A)$ be the number (count) of negative eigenvalues of matrix $A$. We want to compute $I_\sigma=\mathcal{C}(K-\sigma ZZ^T)$.
As demonstrated in above Answer, we have $I_\sigma=\mathcal{C}\left(I_N-Y{(Y^TY-\frac{1}{\sigma}I_r)}^{-1}Y^T\right)$ with $Y=L^{-1}Z$, $K=LL^T$.

Comment: [part 2/3] By applying Woodbury (again) to the inverse of the arg. of $\mathcal{C}$, we obtain $I_\sigma=\mathcal{C}(I_N-\sigma YY^T)$, which yields $I_\sigma=\mathcal{C}(\frac{1}{\sigma}I_N-YY^T)$.
It should be noted that $YY^T$ and $Y^TY$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues. The eigendecomp. $(YY^T)\Phi_Y=\Phi_Y\begin{bmatrix}
\Lambda_Y&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ such that $YY^T=\Phi_Y\begin{bmatrix}\Lambda_Y&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\Phi_Y^T$ and $\Phi_Y\Phi_Y^T=I_N$ yields $I_\sigma=\mathcal{C}\left(\Phi_Y\left(\frac{1}{\sigma}I_N-\begin{bmatrix}\Lambda_Y&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right)\Phi_Y^T\right)$.

Comment: [part 3/3] Consequently, one has $I_\sigma=\mathcal{C}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma}I_N-\begin{bmatrix}\Lambda_Y&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right)$, which is given by $I_\sigma=\mathcal{C}(\frac{1}{\sigma}I_r-\Lambda_Y)$ or $I_\sigma=\mathcal{C}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma}}I_r-\Sigma_Y)$, with $\Sigma_Y=\sqrt{\Lambda_Y}$ the matrix of the singular values of $Y$.

Comment: ... Actually, we don't need to use Woodbury at all, because:
$M=ZZ^T$,
$K=LL^T$,
$Y=L^{-1}Z$, then
$\mathcal{C}(K-\sigma M)=\mathcal{C}(LL^T-\sigma ZZ^T)=\mathcal{C}\left(L^{-1}(LL^T-\sigma ZZ^T)L^{-T}\right)=\mathcal{C}(I_N-\sigma YY^T)$

Comment: Actually... I just realized that all this is useless to my initial problem because it can actually be entirely solved with the same cost. The $r$ eigenvectors with finite eigenvalues of the generalized eigenproblem (GEP) $K\Phi=M\Phi\Lambda$ with $M=ZZ^T$ belong to the image of $S=K^{−1}Z$. By projecting the GEP onto $S$ yields the $(r\times r)$ GEP $AX=A^2X\Lambda$ with $A=Y^TY$, $Y=L^{−1}Z$, $K=LL^T$. This GEP is equivalent to the SEP $AX=X\Lambda^{−1}$. Also, the eigenvectors can be obtained as $\Phi=L^{−T}YX$. The SEP with $Y^TY$ not only gives the inertia count, but all the eigenvalues...

Comment: See this thread https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2294/large-scale-generalized-eigenvalue-problem-with-low-rank-lhs-matrix?rq=1

Comment: I have lost the thread here a bit, would you mind writing your own answer that summarizes the best/streamlined procedure? Then feel free to accept it.. you've certainly made the good faith effort to become the expert on your problem. Overall I think future visitors would be better served if they didn't have to dig so deeply into the commentary.

Comment: @Olivier, would you mind taking rchilton1980 advice on writing your own answer?